# Powershell script appears to execute command with wildcard

Tags: powershell, vmware

I'm writing a PowerShell script that will execute a command on a remote server. I'm using a single variable in the script as a parameter to that command.

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$strUser
)

$strDomain = "company.com\\"
$strFQusername = $strDomain + $strUser

$strFQusername
$strFQusername
$strFQusername

Invoke-Command -computername VMwareView.company.com -scriptblock {. $env:userprofile\document\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1 ; Get-RemoteSession -username $strFQusername } -credential company.com\administrator

$strFQusername
$strFQusername
$strFQusername
```

When I execute this script, the **$strFQusername** variable appears to be replaced by a wildcard. The **Get-RemoteSession** cmdlet is executed correctly, however it lists the sessions for all users, not just the user specified by the **$strFQusername** variable. This would be the equivalent of me entering **Get-RemoteSession -username ***.

If I hard code the username in the script, I get the expected output. That is, I see the session for only the username I hard coded into the script.

I've tried using single and double backslashes in the **$strDomain** variable, but got the same results. The 3 lines of **$strFQusername** you see before and after the Invoke-Command line are there for debugging. They print out exactly the string I would expect to see stored in **$strFQusername**.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Use the modifier `$using` if you have **ps3+** or the paramétrer `-argumentlist` if **ps2**

**Ps3+**:

```
..Get-RemoteSession -username $using:strFQusername
```

**Ps2**

```
...{Param ($user)....Get-RemoteSession -username $user} -arg $strFQusername
```

Answer (score 0):

The scriptblock doesn't know variables outside of it, so you need to pass them into the scriptblock via the `-ArgumentList` parameter:

```
Invoke-Command -computername VMwareView.company.com -scriptblock {
  . $env:userprofile\document\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1;
  Get-RemoteSession -username $args[0]
} -ArgumentList $strFQusername -credential company.com\administrator
```